# Condition under which can a certain collection of elements of a ring $R$ forms an ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a left unital module over a ring $R$. Let $N\subseteq M$ contains $0\in M$ but not necessarily a submodule of $M$. Can some condition be imposed on the the ring $R$ so that the collection $\{r\in R: rm\in N \forall m\in N\}$ forms a left ideal of $R$?

If we define $rm=0 \forall m\in N$, then the above collection is the annihilator of $N$ and hence an ideal. But I am not sure whether the same can be concluded without considering the scalar multiplication.

Comment: It seems to me that the set under consideration contains the unit of $R$, since $m = 1 \cdot m \in N$ for all $m \in N$, so for it to be an ideal, it would have to be $R$ itself.

Comment: Yes this is so. But my intention is to put some condition on the ring $R$ so that the collection always becomes an ideal. Thank you anyway.

Comment: My point is that the question 'When is the set an ideal?' and 'When is the set equal to $R$?' are equivalent. Have you considered what happens in the case $M = R$ and $N = \{0,1\}$?